# how to use Chinese font in this latex template?

Tags: fonts, latex3

I'm creating a CV. My template is in English and I need a Chinese version. I'm confused about how to use Chinese fonts. The following is the template. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Developer CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (28/1/19)
%
% This template originates from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Authors:
% Jan Vorisek (jan@vorisek.me)
% Based on a template by Jan Küster (info@jankuester.com)
% Modified for LaTeX Templates by Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[9pt]{developercv} % Default font size, values from 8-12pt are recommended

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth} % 45% of the page width for name
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages

    % If your name is very short, use just one of the lines below
    % If your name is very long, reduce the font size or make the minipage wider and reduce the others proportionately
    \colorbox{black}{{\HUGE\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{}}}}} % First name

    \colorbox{black}{{\HUGE\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{}}}}} % Last name

    \vspace{6pt}

    {\huge Network Science Postdoctoral} % Career or current job title
\end{minipage}
\hfill \hfill \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth} % 27.5% of the page width for the first row of icons
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages

    % The first parameter is the FontAwesome icon name, the second is the box size and the third is the text
    % Other icons can be found by referring to fontawesome.pdf (supplied with the template) and using the word after \fa in the command for the icon you want
    \icon{MapMarker}{12}{}\\
    \icon{Phone}{12}{+86 }\\
    \icon{At}{12}{\href{mailto:}{}}\\   
\end{minipage}
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.275\textwidth} % 27.5% of the page width for the second row of icons
%   \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages

    % The first parameter is the FontAwesome icon name, the second is the box size and the third is the text
    % Other icons can be found by referring to fontawesome.pdf (supplied with the template) and using the word after \fa in the command for the icon you want
    %\icon{Globe}{12}{\href{https://alyx.vance.me}{alyx.vance.me}}\\
    %\icon{Github}{12}{\href{https://github.com/alyxvance}{github.com/alyxvance}}\\
    %\icon{Twitter}{12}{\href{https://twitter.com/@alyxvance}{@alyxvance}}\\
%\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION, SKILLS AND TECHNOLOGIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsect{Who Am I?}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth} % 40% of the page width for the introduction text
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip} 
    \vspace{2pt}



\begin{center}
    \bubbles{5/Network,     3/Statistics,      5/Computer,    2/Biology}
\end{center}

    %\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem\\ % Dummy text
\end{minipage}
\hfill % Whitespace between
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} % 50% of the page for the skills bar chart
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
    \begin{barchart}{5.5}
            \baritem{Julia}{90}
            \baritem{C++}{80}
            \baritem{Python}{80}
        \baritem{JavaScript}{90}
        \baritem{Matlab}{90}
        \baritem{PHP}{90}       
    \end{barchart}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsect{Experience}

\begin{entrylist}


\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsect{Education}

\begin{entrylist}

\end{entrylist}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsect{Professional activities}

\begin{entrylist}

\end{entrylist}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  PUBLICATION LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsect{Publications}
\begin{itemize}





\end{itemize}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Professional activities
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}


\end{minipage}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: To insert shorter passages in Chinese, you might use `babel` with `\babelprovide[import]{chinese-simplified)` and `\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}[...]{...}`. (Or chinese-traditional if appropriate.) For longer documents, you might use `ctex`.`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}`

Source: `texdoc ctex`, *section 5.3*

`scheme=plain`：

> 不调整默认字号和行距，不会汉化文档中的标题名字，也不会将章节标题风格修改为中文样式，同时不会调整 \pagestyle，并禁用 autoindent 选项。事实上，此时的 CTEX 宏集只提供了中文支持功能，而不对文章版式进行任何修改。
>
> The default font size and line spacing will not be adjusted, the title names in the document will not be finished, nor will the chapter title style be changed to Chinese style, and the \pagestyle will not be adjusted, and the autoindent option will be disabled. In fact, the CTEX macro set at this time only provides Chinese support functions without any modification to the article layout.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{developercv}
\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \colorbox{black}{{\HUGE\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Alyx}}}}}
    
    \colorbox{black}{{\HUGE\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Vance}}}}}
    
    \vspace{6pt}
    
    {\huge Web 应用程序架构师}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```